# Problem involving $\Bbb{Z} [\sqrt{5}]$ and differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $a \gt 2$ and $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as follows:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \\[2ex]
\frac {1}{q^a}, & \text{if $x$ is rational, $x=\frac {p}{q}$, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $p \in \Bbb Z$, $q \in \Bbb N$, $q \gt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Show that $f$ is differentiable on the sets $\Bbb Z [\sqrt d]$, where $d \in \Bbb N$ and $\sqrt d \notin \Bbb N$.

Comment: What have you tried, can you show it for $\sqrt{d}\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Since differentiability implies continuity, $ f $ should be continuous on $ \mathbb{Z} $, but that doesn't look like it is the case since $ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, f(k) = 1 $, right?